# Scribe + Xing => Invalid OAuth signature

Tags: oauth, scribe, xing

I'm trying to use scribe with XING and I'm always getting following answer:

```
Can't extract token and secret from this: '{"message":"Invalid OAuth signature","error_name":"INVALID_OAUTH_SIGNATURE"}'
```

I have a working login process, get back an `oauth_token` and an `oauth_verifier` and tried to to change the defaultly selected `HMACSha1` Singature with a `PlainText` signature, but I'll always get the above mentioned result...

Any ideas on why this happens?

Using the default `DefaultApi10a` and `XingApi` from scribe always fails at the above mentioned step...

**EDIT - Code**

```
// Creating the service
// callback is needed to stop redirecting in the webview
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
            .provider(XingApi.class)
            .apiKey(apiKey)
            .apiSecret(apiSecret)
            .callback("http://www.xing.com")
            .build();
```

*Step 1: get request token + auth url*

```
RequestToken requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
String authUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken );
```

*Step 2: load the auth url in a webview + check the redirect url and cancel redirection based on callback*

for example, redirection url look like following: `http://www.xing.com?oauth_token=a2191ab84c9e0f85cf0c&oauth_verifier=4978`

*Step 3: extract oauth_token + oauth_verifier from returned url*

```
String oauthToken = ...; // a2191ab84c9e0f85cf0c in the example
String oauthVerifier = ...; // 4978 in the example
```

*Step 4: get access token => this fails*

```
Token requestToken = new Token(oauthToken, oauthVerifier); // reusing the request token from above results in invalid request token answer from xing!
Verifier v = new Verifier(oauthVerifier);
Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, v);
```

Comment: Just tested it with `XingExample` - it works.

Comment: I added some code, do you see any problem there?

Comment: What is `mService` ?

Comment: Just forgot to rename this variable, it's the service variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove:

`Token requestToken = new Token(oauthToken, oauthVerifier); // reusing the request token from above results in invalid request token answer from xing!`

line from step 4.

You have to keep request token to retrieve access token using it and verifier (4 digits PIN) from Xing.

**EDIT - code added:**

```
OAuth10aService service = new ServiceBuilder()
    .apiKey("44a4f9c1a9daa88f4da2")
    .apiSecret("2fc8ca373dab772acc4de7ce22718f8fced6919c")
    .callback("https://redirect.example.com")
    .build(XingApi.instance());

final Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();

System.out.println(service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken));
System.out.println("Paste the verifier here");
System.out.print(">>");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Verifier verifier = new Verifier(in.nextLine());
System.out.println();
in.close();

// Trade the Request Token and Verfier for the Access Token
Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
System.out.println("Got the Access Token! " + accessToken);
```

Comment: When I use 'service.getRequestToken()' there I get the 'invalid request token' answer from xing. Does it have to be the same? I'll try to use the same instance tomorrow...

Comment: `Token requestToken = new Token(oauthToken, oauthVerifier)` is wrong, remove it.

Comment: Actually, I'm using my code for years already and never saw that mistake, Xing is I thnik the 14th network I add to my app... REUSING the original request token solves the problem, now I just have to check if the other services work this way as well. Thanks